# Keras Metric for bucketizing a regression output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How do I define a custom keras metric for computing accuracy like so,

```
y_true = [12.5, 45.5]
y_predicted = [14.5, 29]
splits = [-float("inf"), 10, 20, 30, float("inf")]

"""
Splits to Classes translation =>
Class 0: -inf to 9
Class 1: 10 to 19
Class 2: 20 to 29
Class 3: 30 to inf
"""
# using the above translation, 
y_true_classes = [1, 3]
y_predicted_classes = [1, 2]

accuracy = K.equal( y_true_classes, y_predicted_classes ) # => 0.5 here

return accuracy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea on how you might you around implementing this (although probably not the best one).

```
def convert_to_classes(vals, splits):
    out = tf.zeros_like(vals, dtype=tf.int32)

    for split in splits:
        out = tf.where(vals > split, out + 1, out)

    return out


def my_acc(splits):
    def custom_acc(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = convert_to_classes(y_true, splits)
        y_pred = convert_to_classes(y_pred, splits)

        return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, y_pred))
    return custom_acc
```

The function `convert_to_classes` converts the floats to bucks, assuming the bounds are always +-inf.

The closure `my_acc` lets you define the splits (without +-inf) at compile time (added statically to the graph), and then returns a metric function as expected with keras.

Testing using tensorflow:

```
y_true = tf.constant([12.5, 45.5])
y_pred = tf.constant([14.5, 29])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(my_acc((10, 20, 30))(y_true, y_pred)))
```

gives the expected 0.5 accuracy.

And quick test with Keras:

```
x = np.random.randn(100, 10)*100
y = np.random.randn(100)*100

model = Sequential([Dense(20, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(1, activation=None)])
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=[my_acc(splits=(10, 20, 30))])

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

Given the metric (named as the inner function in the closure `custom_acc`)

```
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 10242.2591 - custom_acc: 0.4300
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 53us/step - loss: 10101.9658 - custom_acc: 0.4200
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 53us/step - loss: 10011.4662 - custom_acc: 0.4300
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 51us/step - loss: 9899.7181 - custom_acc: 0.4300
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 50us/step - loss: 9815.1607 - custom_acc: 0.4200
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 74us/step - loss: 9736.5554 - custom_acc: 0.4300
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 50us/step - loss: 9667.0845 - custom_acc: 0.4400
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 58us/step - loss: 9589.5439 - custom_acc: 0.4400
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 61us/step - loss: 9511.8003 - custom_acc: 0.4400
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 51us/step - loss: 9443.9730 - custom_acc: 0.4400
```

Comment: your convert to classes function is amazing! As you are looping through each split to identify the right class instead of directly computing it is why you feel this may not be the most optimal way?